# Assign null php variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I pass null PHP variable to javascript?

My code is as:

```
<?php

$size = null;

<< Call Rest API >>
if (<some_condition_here>) {
    $size = <rest_api_value>;
}
echo "<input name='diff_size' id='diff_limit' type='test' value='$size' />";

<script>
var initial_value = $size

function checkIfChanged() {
    if ($('diff_size').val() == initial_val )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
?>
```

<< On submit javascript function is called >>

Error message:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

var initial_value = ;

Comment: You want to wrap $size in quotes otherwise the JavaScript might get parsing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$size = null;

<< Call Rest API >>
if (<some_condition_here>) {
    $size = <rest_api_value>;
}
echo "<input name='diff_size' id='diff_limit' type='test' value='$size' />";
?>
<script>
var initial_value = '<?= $size ?>';

function checkIfChanged() {
    if ($('diff_size').val() == initial_val )
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

</script>
```